# Modify a PNG image in the drawable folder

Tags: android, android-drawable

I have a PNG file in my drawable folder.
I need to modify it merging on it a smaller image.
I use this code for create a new Bitmap

```
Bitmap bigImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.i10);
Bitmap smallImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.i11);

        Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(bigImage.getWidth(), bigImage.getHeight(), bigImage.getConfig());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);

        canvas.drawBitmap(bigImage, 0f, 0f, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(smallImage, 10, 10, null);
```

That I miss is the final part. Assign the new bitmap (bigImage) to "R.drawable.i10"

Answer (score 1):

Resources are static, you cannot change those files once they are shipped in the app (Apk)...

However you can create/manipulate the existing ones & save it as a new file on Storage but that's a different thing & not related with the question!

Comment: Ok I understand now. Thanks!